# Javascript CRM Conversion Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working in a Corporate Real Estate CRM.  Javascript is allowed but not supported.  When I insert this:

```
<script>

function tick(){
    $('#ticker li:first').slideUp( function () { $(this).appendTo($('#ticker')).slideDown(); });
}
setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 5000);
```

The code is converted to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    function tick(){
        $('#ticker li:first').slideUp( function () { $(this).appendTo($('#ticker')).slideDown(); });
    }
    setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 5000);
// ]]></script>
```

How do I fix this problem?  Thanks in advance for helping a "newbie"!

Alex T.

Comment: What exactly is "this problem"? The 
CDATA wrapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what server-side functionality is doing that, but that's actually sensible and nothing to worry about.

The modifications to the `<script>` and `</script>` tags are to

1. explicitly specify the language
2. prevent non-javascript browsers from rendering (at least most of) the javascript into the page.

Comment: Michael, Thanks for your response.  I apologize for not being more clear.  I cannot figure out why this particular Javascript function is not working and I assumed it had something to do with the code change.  The ticker is supposed to show only the first four news items.  Here is a link to the page:  http://www.hattiesburghomes.remax-mississippi.com/